# Error: Unexpected null value while implementing flutter_google_places [flutter web]

Tags: flutter, google-places-api, flutter-web

I am using the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places package in flutter web to pick the location from google place API
but it throws an error as

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
```

or sometimes

```
Error: Unexpected null value.
```

I tried to find out a solution and got one temporary solution,
i added one argument in `PlacesAutocomplete.show()` method as

```
proxyBaseUrl: kIsWeb
              ? 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api'
             : null,
```

this link provides me temporary access to google places but after some hours it expires and needs to request again manually from this link, so it is not a workable solution at all.

so, anyone who knows how to implement [flutter_google_places](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places) in flutter web then kindly helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this version `flutter_google_places_hoc081098: ^1.1.0`. it seems that one has problems.